# How to insert a character between any several characters without knowing indexes?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, boolean-computation

There is a list of strings:

```
{"x1x2", "x1", "x1x2x3", "x3", "x4", "x1x2x3x4"}
```

The goal is to insert "&&" between every two elements in a list.
I need to get a result:

```
{"x1&&x2", "x1", "x1&&x2&&x3", "x3", "x4", "x1&&x2&&x3&&x4"}
```

It's not difficult to do it by hand in this case, but it's not a desirable solution. I found only one function that can help with this task (String Insert []) but it works with indexes and doesn't help to deal with this task. 
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like it is a part of a bigger problem that might be solved easier. Consider an extended post. I suspect something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you want ?

```
StringJoin[Riffle[Partition[Characters[#], 2], "&&"]] & /@ {"x1x2", 
  "x1", "x1x2x3", "x3", "x4", "x1x2x3x4"}
```

(* Out: {"x1&&x2", "x1", "x1&&x2&&x3", "x3", "x4", "x1&&x2&&x3&&x4"} *)

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
lst = {"x1x2", "x1", "x1x2x3", "x3", "x4", "x1x2x3x4"};
```

You can use a combination of [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html) and [`StringPartition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringPartition.html)

```
StringRiffle[StringPartition[#, 2], "&&"] & /@ lst
```

> {"x1&&x2", "x1", "x1&&x2&&x3", "x3", "x4", "x1&&x2&&x3&&x4"}

Alternatively, you can use [`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html):

```
StringReplace[lst, d : DigitCharacter .. ~~ a : LetterCharacter :> d <> "&&" <> a]
```

> {"x1&&x2", "x1", "x1&&x2&&x3", "x3", "x4", "x1&&x2&&x3&&x4"}